# Setting Up An Android/Maven Library Project in Intellij

Tags: android, maven, intellij-idea

As you can see from my passed 3 questions I am having major problems with my project setup. I am getting lots of very specific errors that seems like nobody can answer them. I am getting hugely frustrated. So I am going to try a fresh approach. I will describe how I would like my project set up and if somebody could give me some brief steps to follow I would be very grateful. After messing around with this for around a week I believe I have some knowledge but maven seems to be incredibly difficult to understand.

I am writing a library which will be used in 2 projects. The major libraries I would like to use are roboguice, robolectric and jackson(json library). I would like to have a way to test the library but I am unsure if this should be in a different module or not. Robolectric seems to suggest it should be in the same module. I am unsure how I should use this library in the other 2 projects. I have been looking at this http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/ApkLib but unfortunately the website tells me next to nothing about how I should create the apklib.

If it is possible I would also like the other 2 projects to have a dependency on that library and build it automatically.

I have been using this site to create the maven project http://stand.spree.de/wiki_details_maven_archetypes

But I have been running into issue after issue. If anybody can point me in the right direction I will be very appreicative

Comment: The best place to start learning android-maven-plugin is [maven-android-plugin-samples](https://github.com/jayway/maven-android-plugin-samples), it contains several projects that cover almost all common use cases. have a play with those samples and make sure you have a general idea of how it configured and work, before starting using it in your own project.

Comment: that helped me a lot actually. I guess I will answer my question when I can be bothered as there is a fair bit to it

Answer (score 3):

Even if maven is (almost) a foreign country to me, I had some moderate success setting up a maven project and interacting with it using intellij. I wanted to use it because it looked the easiest way to have robolectric working with intellij.

I wrote a blogpost you can find [here](http://mytechaddiction.blogspot.it/2012/07/intellij-robolectric-and-android.html)

What you need is:

- Maven android sdk deployer https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer
- Maven android plugin http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/GettingStarted (using android archetypes is just fine)

If you want to build an apk lib instead of an apk, just specify *apklib* in the packaging tag

PS: I also saw [this](http://code.google.com/p/android-maven-robolectric-roboguice-example/) a while ago, but never gave it a try.